# keep storage when changing location in ios safari private browsing mode

Tags: javascript, ios, html, safari, html5-history

I'm using html5 web storage to save and load data when a user changes pages, but it doesn't work in iOS Safari private browsing mode.

Is there another way (pure JavaScript) to transfer data between pages without involving the server (i.e., cookies)?  I'm trying to keep it as fast as possible.

I'm not familiar with the html5 history API, but can that be used for this purpose?

I'm aware that i can use a hash in the URL, but that seems unsightly.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can use cookies for this:

```
// cookie for ios safari private browsing between pages
function getCookieValue(key) {
    return grep(document.cookie.split(/;\s*/), function (cookie) {
        return cookie.indexOf(key + '=') == 0;
    }).map(function (cookie) {
        return decodeURIComponent(cookie.replace(key + '=', ''));
    })[0];
}

function cookieStorage() {
    var cookies = {};
    document.cookie.split(/;\s*/).forEach(function(cookie){
        var split = cookie.split('=');
        cookies[split[0]] = decodeURIComponent(split.slice(1).join('='));
    });
    return cookies;
}

function clearCookies() {
    document.cookie.split(/;\s*/).forEach(function (cookie) {
        // have to set path as they may have been set from a different page
        document.cookie = cookie.split('=', 1)[0] + '=;path=/;expires=' + new Date().toUTCString();
    });
}

function setCookie(key, s) {
    // have to set path so we can clear them from a different page
    document.cookie = key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(s) + ';path=/';
}
```